# firestore error handling for insert, update, delete

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For get(), this is how I handle error:

for single doc:

```
const user = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('123').get()
if(!user.exist){
    throw new Error("get failed")
}
```

for multiple docs:

```
const {docs} = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').get()
if(docs?.length < 1){
    throw new Error("no data found")
}
```

Should I handle errors like the logic below?

```
const res = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc().set({name: 'Ben'})
if(!res){
    throw new Error("insert failed")
}

...

const res = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('123').update({name: 'Ben'})
if(!res){
    throw new Error("update failed")
}

...

const res = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('123').delete()
if(!res){
    throw new Error("delete failed")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try catch` which will need to be executed in async block like this:

```
async function sample() {
    try {
        const res = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc().set({
            name: 'Ben'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error inserting document:', error);
        // handle the error or throw a new error with a custom message
    }
}
```

Or If you want to catch the error immediately then you can use the following by appending the `.catch()` method:

```
async function sample() {
      const res = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc().set({
          name: 'Ben'
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

And it seems like you are using the firebase V8 version. This can be solved easily by upgrading to firebase modular SDK v9.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what can be solved by upgrading to fb modular SDK v9?

Comment: You are writing `firebase.firestore()` multiple times. That can be neglected with firebase modular SDK v9. With the v9 you can just import the required methods for insert, update and delete like addDoc, updateDoc, deleteDoc respectively.

Comment: Let me know if the above suggestions were helpful or are you looking for something else?